# searchController searchBar text color change in modal presented ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uinavigationbarappearance

have the following setup a root TabBarController the second index have a navigation bar that holds a viewController, for clarity call viewController A, a have a button to modal present a view controller with have a tableview, this tableview has as header a search controller search bar, lets call this viewController B, A viewController has another button to push a new view controller lest call C. C has a searchBar and navigation items is set to text color of search bar to be white.

if do A -> B, B searchController searchBar text color is black. if I go A -> C then go back and A -> B then B searchController searchBar text color is white like C.

tried to set the text color like in `viewDidLoad this but not result

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor =  UIColor(named: "supportDarkest")
    }
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(named: "supportDarkest")
```

set this in viewWillAppear but nothing change.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor =  UIColor(named: "supportDarkest")
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor =  UIColor(named: "supportDarkest")
        searchController.searchBar.tintColorDidChange()
    }
}
```

B in normal textColor
[image]
C in normal mode
[image]
B after pushing C goes back and present B
[image]
here the searchTextfield textColor is white. and want it black.

Comment: Looks like you are changing the tint color of the navigation bar in C. Mind that they are all the same navigation bar unless you intentionally change controllers.

Comment: yes in c is changed but B is presented not pushed, so no navigationController for B, unless im wrong

Answer (score 0):

It should work, check supportDarkest name is same as per assets. or try to check with any system color first like:

```
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .red
```

or you can try this too:

```
searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .black
```

Comment: the name is correct checked several times. if not pushed C the text color is supportDarkest after pushing C go back and present B the text color became white because C has a UINavigationApparence to use text color in white, and for some reason that value get passed to B even when B has not Navigation controller or any like that.

Comment: same result red first before pushing c and white after go back and present B

Comment: setup barStyle didn't work either?